# iOS app crashes because images use too much ram

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is a stupid problem, but this is my first real app that I have to make, I have no one to ask and I looked up this problem and found no other similar problems.

My app crashes on real devices with no exception. I saw in the simulator that uses too much RAM and after a while I got to the conclusion that the pictures I am using are to blame.

The app is structured in this way: it has 8 viewControllers for different things: for example, it starts with one which lets the user select the avatar with which he/she will play and here I have two pictures, next is a viewController which shows the stats for that avatar and here it is another picture and so on. The problem is that each picture uses 40MB of RAM to be displayed and things add up so the app uses more than 300MB of RAM when the user gets to the gameviewCOntroller where the game is. Because of this, on devices like iPAD 2 or iphone 4 it crashes, but not on iphone 5.

I tried to set the images both from "images.xcassets" and from a ".atlas" folder, but the result is exactly the same. The pictures have a dimension of no more than 1500x1999px, they are in png format.

Also, I saw that if the app were to start directly into the gaveViewController it would use 180MB so the other viewController remain in memory or something like that. Should I "clear" them or something similar?

```
//-------update-------
```

This is what I got from Instruments:
[image]

Comment: are you making your button Programetacally

Comment: Verify if you have some loops that consume memory without releasing at the end

Comment: You should try to use Instruments to see where all the memory goes. You can also debug with a real iPhone.

Comment: the buttons are not made programmatically. I positioned them with auto layout constraints. I don't think this is a loop. I mean as soon as I add an image to the imageView(no matter which) the RAM consumption jumps with 40MB like that. p.s. I do not remove the imageVIew, I just leave it with no picture

Comment: I didn't even knew about Instruments. I am checking that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Memory is a big deal on mobile devices, there is not a clear answer to you question, but I can give you some advices:

- If your images are plain colors or have symmetric axes use resizable images. You can just use one line of pixel multiplied by with or height to cover the entire screen using a small amount of memory
- Image compression doens't have effects when the image is decompressed. So if you have a png that is 600kb and you are thinking that converting in a 300kb will lower memory usage is only true for "disk space" when an image is decompressed in memory the size is `widthXheightXNumber_of_channelXbit_for_channel`
- resize images: if are loading a 2000px square image into memory and you show it inside an image view of 800 px square, resize before adding it.You will have just a peak while resizing, but later it will use less memory
- If you need to use big images, use tiling techniques such as `CATiledLayer`
- If you don't need an image anymore get rid of it. It's ok to have an array of path to images, but not an array of full uncompressed images
- Avoid `-imageNamed` it caches images and even if Apple says that this cache is released under memory pressure, you don't have a lot of control on it and it could be too late to avoid a crash

Those are general advices, it's up to you if they fit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you guys, your both answers helped me very much. I have followed your answers and now I the app doesn't even reaches 70MB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely follow Andrea's advices.
Additionally you should consider setting the image size to exactly what your need is. You're saying that you've tried to set them from xcassets so you have full control over the images you're loading, which is great (compared to downloading an image that you cannot modify).

I highly suggest you [read some documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) on using Asset catalog files. This will allow you to have high-resolution image for bigger screens that also have more memory, and smaller ones for older devices, which is what you want here.

Also, note that 1500x1999px is still a very big size for most mobile devices.
More links about screen-size:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html
- http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: Thank you guys, your both answers helped me very much. I have followed your answers and now I the app doesn't even reaches 70MB of RAM.